# Using BindingNavigatorMovePreviousItem with Labels to manipulated data

Tags: vb.net, bindingnavigator

So here's my problem. Im using a BindingNavigator along with a TableAdapter, a Dataset, a TableAdaptor and a TableAdapterManager to manipulated some data from my database. I set a button to interact with the BindingNavigator as MovePreviousItem command. I noticed that instead of displaying the previous Label.Text is displays an entirely diffrent string as before. Example:

[image: First Set of Label Text]

[image: After Clicking The Previous Button]

Im bot sure where to look if this was caused by the coding lines or directly by the dataadapter. I think the Text is overwriten by the the asnwerstring from the database and the txtCorrectAnswer.Text value. Any suggestions, where i should look into? thanks

Comment: b) Cougar as it's the only animal predominately found in the americas

Comment: lolz. its actually elephant. the other 3 belongs to the cat(feline) family. and i wasnt asking bout the question content :)